# Merging Bibliographies

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I have several `.bib` files, which I'd like to merge together into one. Due to the considerable effort involved in doing it manually I am looking for tool support.

The only tool I found so far is [PyBib](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/pybib.html), which supposedly is capable of merging bib files. However, it appears to be not very polished and breaks easily. After fixing the missing `BIBPATH` environment variable, it still could not read my bib files properly and complained about syntax errors. In particular, entries that use `VARIABLE # { and some text }` break the parser.

Are there any other tools available, or which way would you go to merge a bunch of `.bib` files. I am sure some manual checking is required, but I'd like not to do the whole process by hand.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[JabRef](http://jabref.sourceforge.net/) may help.

When you try to import a new file to current one, it will examine and label all duplicates automatically. What you need do is just clicking the 'deselect' button.

Comment: Could you please elaborate that? Does it work as I think: you append the databases, then use scan>check duplicates ?

Comment: @Frank: That's what I would do. There may be a few false-positives but it generally does a good job.

Answer (score 2):

The [bibtools](http://ctan.org/pkg/bibtools) collection contains `makebib` which appears to do what you are looking for.